# How to maintain your professional status and not get troubled by the junior lecturers

Tags: academic-life, work-life-balance, colleagues, harassment

A new senior lecturer, say A has been assigned to work in doing some tutorials with a set of assistant lecturers. These assistant lecturers, say B1, B2, B3 etc. don’t know some of the theoretical concepts properly.

Sometimes, in the middle of the tutorials they try to ask and clarify things from each other. Since, there is a group of lecturers per class, usually they do the tutorials by taking turns. The subject X is A’s specialized area, so that when classes from that subject are going on, A even teach the other assistant lecturers some easy techniques in teaching them too.

There is another subject say Y. It is not A’s exact area and actually when assigning A to that, the management has mentioned that A will be working under "on training" mode. There is a one assistant lecturer, say B4 who has passed out from the same university, and so she also has done it during her undergraduate program. But B4 is also sometimes not very clear about some theoretical sections and for some questions, what she says is not exactly logical. But people have to accept it.

A, B1 and B4 are doing a class on Y together. Since it had been bit difficult for A and also because of some other works, A couldn’t catch up at once and so for about 3 weeks, A has kind of stayed in the background, looking at B1 and B4 doing the class. Actually, sometimes B1,B4 also get stuck at questions, and also, what they basically do is letting the students do the tutorial questions by themselves and explain the places they get errors only. They don’t explain anything on the board or anything. So, there wasn’t anything much A could catch up from being there and observing them either. In the 4th week, however there was a theoretical part that A is familiar with, so that A explained it while B1 and B4, now stood at the back. A’s explanations were good and so B4 was feeling kind of remorseful, it appeared like that.

After a few days, another assistant lecturer, said “Oh, it’s not good if people are not taking turns to do the classes. B4 said there’s someone in her class who is not taking turns with them” as if to hint at A, loudly so that A can hear. It kind of hurt A, because, B1 and B4 could have directly told A, if they wanted to take turns and also A was just put as on training person, so A didn’t think about it much, that it’ll be a problem for them.

Is there a way that A can respond to this situation (may be in a lighthearted and bantering way) but still defend herself and gain her a good respect?

I mean, many people, when others say something, defend themselves. What can A say to imply that it's not A's fault and even B1,B4 is not doing things properly, so why would B4 try to point a finger at A like this...

Comment: To me, this question is unclear. It would be improved by shortening the back story and clarifying the question you want addressed.

Comment: The story does not sound to me like "being harassed by junior lecturers".

Comment: @BryanKrause if A don't react to this situation, she'll be having to hear more and more such comments, and eventually they'll start harassing her

Comment: Okay @Ian I've made edits as mentioned. Can you please see now?

Comment: I have serious difficulty following questions like this one that include unnecessary placeholder names for individuals.

Comment: from what you've written I'm guessing this is culture dependent, you appear to be from a high context society ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-context_and_low-context_cultures ) which may mean you are skirting around the question you want to ask, making it impossible for us to answer. You are also a woman and depending on culture this might be important to understand your story. It would be good to include your culture (and where you work) for context. Re-writing this as being about you and stating your concerns first before providing the background story would also help readability.

Comment: As a side note, I'm wondering if the high context/skirting around what you want to say (very useful in face-saving environments) might be part of the reason you had issues in the past with papers being misunderstood. Computer science/maths is more low context/explicit, and I know European/North American Countries/Australia all have cultures more on the low context side of things.

Answer (score 3):

> What can A say to imply that it's not A's fault

It's not clear to me that it's not A's fault or that A should try to defend themselves. Rather, it seems like there is a conflict of expectations among the various parties that needs to be resolved.

B4 is going about this in a bit of a passive aggressive way but perhaps they don't feel like they can address A directly due to seniority. If B4 were asking for advice I'd recommend they take a more direct communication approach, but it seems A is asking for advice so my advice is: A needs to pull their own weight in the course and needs to be an adult about dividing responsibility. As the senior party here, even if A is not comfortable with all the material they have to at least be comfortable with coming up with a reasonable division of labor among the instructors that is mutually agreed upon.

I don't think lighthearted or banter will look good for A: this just belittles a colleague and will make A look like a jerk. Instead, I'd recommend being open about what appears to be a conflict: "hey team, I'm getting the impression that you're expecting me to do more for this course than I have been. What division of responsibilities would seem more fair to you?"

You're not required to accept whatever they suggest, but it will start the conversation and hopefully everyone can move forward with shared expectations.

I'll add that there seems to be a lot of contempt by A for their colleagues and a feeling of superiority by A. In this story, A seems egotistical and insecure. I'd recommend a broader reassessment of A's attitude towards junior colleagues; a professional therapist might be useful in this, therapy isn't just for "illness".

Comment: Hi thanks @BryanKrause you mean that B4 is feeling not like telling A to share work, because of her seniority? And also, if B4 and others have been doing the lessons right, A could have gotten the training she needs and would have developed herself to face a shift by herself too? But they are not sure about what they teach, they don't answer some questions and so on, and that's why A is unable to get trained and then what can be done?

Comment: A is learning by herself @BryanKrause but that's why it had taken a bit of time.

Comment: @Hasini It's not normal for an instructor of a course, even an "in training" one, to need to learn so much of the course content from the other instructors, and especially not to blame others for not understanding the material. If you need more guidance about the direction the course is going (upcoming topics, reading lists) you can certainly ask your colleagues for it but it's very immature to just say "oh they didn't teach me so it's not my fault that I can't contribute". That's lazy and unprofessional.

Comment: If I was B4 I am not going to mind that A is not taking turns with me, as it was the class lead by me, before A came (A joined newly in the middle of the semester).  So that's why I think I don't understand why they did such a thing at once, without discussing with A. @BryanKrause then it means that them not knowing the subject is kind of ok? If it was a class lead by A and B4 joined later and B4 observed that A didn't know the subject, usually what type of action will a passive agressive person like B4 will follow? If you guess or have observed from such a similar person?

Comment: I'm asking that just to find out the behaviour

Comment: @Hasini If you're not B4 you don't get to decide what they do and do not mind. You need to have a conversation with your colleagues about your role and take some responsibility for yourself rather than blaming everyone else.

Comment: Yeah will be taking responsibility but am reluctant to give free knowledge like before when they don't know as I don't understand their behaviour @BryanKrause If you were B4 who came late and if it was A's class and A didn't know properly what will you do?

Comment: And I didn't know they were expecting me to contribute. I'm not saying that "oh they didn't teach me so it's not my fault that I can't contribute". They didn't talk about shifting. If they did I would have speeded up my self learning this semester itself.

Comment: @Hasini What do you mean "free knowledge"? It's okay if you didn't know what they expected before, you should have asked rather than assumed but nothing can be changed about the past; now that you've learned differently it's time to have a conversation about it.

Comment: I mean for subject X, also they don't know theories and concepts properly. They come to the lecture and sometimes they get stuck. Then I'm the one who is teaching the correct stuff... To students and also to them.. But I don't feel like doing so now, if I didn't know I think they will go ahead and do something passive agressive rather than telling me. Yeah now anyway I'm going to teach the sessions to students whether they tell or not as they have gone and put a show in an indirect way

Comment: Isn't it part of your job to contribute to teaching this course? You've been assigned to work there. That's not free it's your job.

Comment: Teaching teachers is also my job? When it's their class in the subject X? They have not been put as under training under me...

Comment: That's a conversation to have with your supervisor. I'm not going to contribute further to this conversation, good luck.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Then if it was B4 who came late and have seen A not knowing the subject, B4 would have gone to the supervisor? And also when it's a circumstance related to a subject like X?

Comment: Do you want advice or do you want to complain until someone says you're right and everyone else is wrong?

Comment: Hmm, does this comment look like it suggest like a complaint? I'm sorry about that.. What I was trying to see is that how these people act as that's not how I act. I would rather have had peaceful conversations, and I also have helped. Using my help only they were able to teach the subject X properly, and they get paid. And I was trying to learn Y also by myself. And I didn't know that such a problem was going on and their views. So I feel curious to know if there was a switching of places how they would have acted...I want to know how they think and understand because like

Comment: I told before, my way of thinking is different @BryanKrause Sorry for the trouble though. Thanks a lot too!!! I would have talked with them before too if I knew. On the other hand as I'm peaceful and had been helpful, I kind of feel why they didn't present their problem to me directly eventhough they have enough evidence to see my nature. I've always expressed friendly and humble cooperative conversations to them. That's why I want to understand their behaviour. I've to stay with them in the future too.

Comment: If they just said "can you take the next week session" simply, if they wanted these sessions also to flow like normal sessions even though it was training, I would have taken it. I always have talked like a friend, otherwise, usually people can't come and take advises from another person while teaching you see, but they take from me. Anyone else, would have condemned them I think if they go to ask that many basic questions while working as a teacher, that's what I think they would have done if it happened the otherway round